# How do I tell what is causing Ansible to hang when provisioning Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, freeze, ansible

When using Ansible as a provisioner for Vagrant, if it hangs, I can't find any way of getting debugging information from it on what is causing it to hang.

I've tried `-vvvv` but that doesn't tell me what is causing it to hang.  How can I find out?

Comment: Can you post the `-vvv` output leading up to the hang?

Comment: I'm not trying to find out what causes it in this specific instance; I'm trying to find out whether there is anyway to get the information for debugging purposes.  If not, then I'm pretty much thinking of giving up on Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out that this was related to the fact that I was using Vagrant with Ansible as a provisioner.

A support person from Ansible told me that in those circumstances, I should:

- Run ansible with -vvv.
- Login to the remote host where the command is being executed.
- Find the ansible process executing the command and kill them.
- The stdout and stderr should be printed to the console where ansible was running.